# How to make C program wait (on Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, wait, mpi

How to make C program wait (on Linux)? (I need to use wait with MPI - I need C code please)

Comment: sleep() from unistd.h? what do you mean by 'wait'? Just stop for a given amount of time or wait for another process to do something?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to wait for a MPI request use MPI_Wait: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/MPI_Wait/

If you want to wait a certain amount of time use sleep: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/

If you want to wait another process to end use waitpid: http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid

If you want to wait a condition variable (multi-threaded programming) use pthread_cond_wait: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html

Define what you want to wait for.

Comment: And if you want MPI processes to wait on each other you might want to use mpi_barrier

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sleep(seconds)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/)

Comment: Or `nanosleep` in case he wants to wait less than a second: http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/nanosleep/ (it was clear from the link, but people skip right past links sometimes)

Answer (score 2):

Wait for *what* exactly ? If you just want a delay use `sleep()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MPI_Recv](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Recv.html), and use [MPI_Send](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Send.html) to send a message to the waiting process when it should continue.