# How to make a c program wait on linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a program that sends ARP requests, it basically asks all the ip's on a network what their mac adress is. So i need the program to wait for 100 miliseconds for a response, otherwise ask the next mac adress what its mac is.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566073/how-to-make-c-program-wait-on-linux

Comment: Search engine is your good friend.

Comment: @AdamLiss it does not answer my question, i do not want it to sleep because if it sleeps, i will not listen to the ARP response (the device's mac adress), i am trying the select() function but i am not sure on how it works.

Comment: @ÁngelCáceresLicona So you may use another thread to watch events.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=use+select+to+wait

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin something like that, i have no idea how to do it on c or i do not undersatnd the select() function.

Comment: @AdamLiss it seems like i did not do enough research, thanks a lot.

Comment: while your program is sleeping, your computer will continue to get the network data.  You won't be able to process it until you're done sleeping, but you won't lose the data while you're sleeping.

Comment: Use a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)